# Find All URLs on Page Using jQuery

Tags: jquery, url, find

I need to find all the URLs on the page using jQuery.

They will be static URLS, by that I mean not within anchor tags.

Comment: Are we assuming the URLs have been normalised? Do they include "http://", etc., or does "example.com" count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to find all of the literal text URLs - e.g. ones that are not part of an `<a>`, this should work:

```
var regex = /https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?/ig;
var matches = regex.exec($('body').text());
```

Comment: You need to escape all your backslashes... Alternatively, use a literal regex.

Comment: Also, you need a global flag.

Answer (score 2):

How about taking all the content of the document and parse it using a regexp?

To know if a string is a url:

```
function isUrl(s) {
var regexp = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/
return regexp.test(s); }
```

[via](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/452)